# How to compare time values?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote an Excel VBA script to compare time values.

Below is an example of my Excel table.

Column A  Column B  Column C
 21:15   02:24   02:24
 20:39   02:15   02:15
 19:23   03:36   03:36
 23:54   04:11   23:54
 22:52   04:48   22:52
 19:44   05:25   19:44
 18:38   06:00   18:38

In column A and B are time values. The result in column C should be the time in column A if the time in column B is greater than 04:00 otherwise it should be the time in column B.

I wrote function getTime(Sting A, String B) and use it in column C.

```
Function getTime(t1 As String, t2 As String) As String

    Dim temp1, temp2 As Variant

    temp1 = TimeValue(Format(Trim(t1), "hh:mm"))

    temp2 = TimeValue(Format(Trim(t2), "hh:mm"))

    If temp2 >= TimeValue("04:00") Then
        getTime = Format(temp1, "hh:mm")
    Else
        getTime = Format(temp2, "hh:mm")
    End If

End Function
```

The getTime() function is working on any computer but mine.

Column A Column B result on other computer result on my computer

21:15   02:24      02:24         00:01
   20:39   02:15      02:15         02:15
 19:23   03:36      03:36         00:15
 23:54   04:11      23:54         23:54
 22:52   04:48      22:52         00:02
 19:44   05:25      19:44         19:44
 18:38   06:00      18:38         00:25
The problem occurs if the time in column B is 01:12, 02:24, 03:36, 04:48, 06:00 and so on.

Comment: Maybe because of different windows computer time settings?

Comment: Messing with time as strings is going to be tricky, you need to use `Date` variables, and the function must return a `Date` not a `String`

Comment: Could replicate this issue, but dimming all your variables as dates instead solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine on my workbook:

```
Option Explicit
Function getTime(t1 As Date, t2 As Date) As Date

    'everything in this function needs to be a Date, since you are comparing times

    Dim MatchTime As Date
    MatchTime = TimeSerial(4, 0, 0) 'hours, minutes, seconds

    If t2 >= MatchTime Then
        getTime = t1
    Else
        getTime = t2
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: Your time is in minutes or hours, @thinagorn?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to change the type of variables t1, t2 to Date. It's working. You are the best.

Comment: @thinagorn no problem, when working with times/dates always use `Date` variables. You can use `TimeSerial` and `DateSerial` to give value to your variables when it's not given by the function.